# How can I pass parameter to a Java thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a code in abstract class:

```
public abstract class Job implements Runnable{  
    public void start(Integer jobId) {                      
        try {
            new Thread(this).start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }       
    }
}
```

class code:

```
public class Test extends Job {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.currentThread();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("TEST");
        }       
    }
}
```

And in main I have:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws MessagingException  
  {
      Test test = new Test();
      test.start(74); 
  }
```

So how can I pass parameter (jobId) from start method to run()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Job.start()` method, store the value in a member variable, so that you can access it in the `run()` method later, when the thread is started.

```
public abstract class Job implements Runnable {
    protected Integer jobId;

    public void start(Integer jobId) {
        this.jobId = jobId;
        try {
            new Thread(this).start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }       
    }
}

public class Test extends Job {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(jobId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change that to a constructor parameter, and store it in a field in the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

Make `jobId` as member variable of Abstract Class, and in `start` method, set this variable.
Now this variable will be accessible in `run()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the constructor's parameter to the thread:

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {

   public MyThread(int parameter) {
   // store parameter for later user
   }

   public void run() {
   }
}
```

and call like this:

```
Runnable r = new Thread(new MyThread(param_value)).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way. But i am sure that not the best. As i said before this is the easiest way. :)

```
public abstract class Job implements Runnable{  
    public void start(Integer jobId) {                      
        try {
            // passing jobID
            Test.jobID = this.jobId;
            new Thread(this).start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }       
    }
}
```

And other class..

```
public class Test extends Job {

   public static Integer jobID;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.currentThread();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // print jobID
            System.out.println(this.jobID);
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have done the things right.

Just change

```
  test.start(74);
```

in your `main` to

```
 test.start(new Integer(74));
```

You can validate it by printing `jobId` in `start` method of `Job` class.

**If you want to access the field in `run` method, define a class variable in "Job`class and use the same in`run` method.**

Answer (score 0):

May I propose you to rethink the way you generate job ids. In all probability you just need a unique id for each new job. The concern of generating that id should reside within your Job class:

```
public abstract class Job implements Runnable {
  private static final AtomicInteger nextId = new AtomicInteger();
  public final int id = nextId.getAndIncrement();

  ... the rest of your class's code ...
}
```